# Is there any way to add DOM elements only with javascript with number index when added?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to find any solution of adding DOM elements with text nodes and adding number index in the nodes only using javascript.

I've tried using if..else and for loop but none of them work.

```
function addElement() {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var add = document.createTextNode("This is newly added. ");
    para.appendChild(add);
    var element = document.getElementById("div1");
    element.appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Please elaborate the question. Are you looking for an existing DOM element indexing, or do you want to create your own indexing?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Take a look at the `innerHTML` property. You may find it easier than what you are trying.

Comment: Can you post what you have been trying so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append one *label* element inside the *p* element with the current length of *p* as the text of the *label*:

```js
function addElement() {
  var length = document.querySelectorAll('p').length;
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var add = document.createTextNode("This is newly added. ");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.textContent = length + ' ';
  para.appendChild(label);
  para.appendChild(add);
  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
}
document.getElementById('createElement').addEventListener('click',addElement);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="createElement">Create Element</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is the exact code what I want.